# Responsive slider is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I am trying to add a responsive slider to my website.

And I decided to follow the codes in http://responsiveslides.com/. However, when I test out the codes in my browser - firefox, the images are not moving meaning I only show immovable image.

I hope someone can point out to me what I had done wrongly based on the things I have done.

My html code is :

```
<div class="callbacks_container">
    <ul class="rslides" id="slider4">
        <li>
            <img src="img/banner01.jpg" alt="">
            <p class="caption">This is a caption</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/banner02.jpg" alt="">
            <p class="caption">This is another caption</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/banner03.jpg" alt="">
            <p class="caption">The third caption</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I added the javascript and the link under the  as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="responsive.js"></script>
<script>

$(function () {
    // Slideshow 4
    $("#slider4".rslides).responsive({
        auto: false,
        pager: false,
        nav: true,
        speed: 500,
        namespace: "callbacks",
        before: function () {
            $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
        },
        after: function () {
            $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script>

$(function () {
    $("#slider4").responsive({
        auto: true,
        pager: false,
        nav: true,
        speed: 800,
        namespace: "callbacks",
    });
});
</script>
```

My CSS is :

```
.rslides {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.rslides li {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.rslides li:first-child {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.rslides img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
.callbacks_container {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.callbacks {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.callbacks li {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.callbacks img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
.callbacks .caption {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: none;
}
.callbacks_nav {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    top: 52%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 3;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 61px;
    width: 38px;
    background: transparent url("themes/themes.gif") no-repeat left top;
    margin-top: -45px;
}
.callbacks_nav:active {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
.callbacks_nav.next {
    left: auto;
    background-position: right top;
    right: 0;
}
```

For the jquery.js I have copied from the Jquery website 1.8.1.3 and attached accordingly.

The responsiveSlides.js I have named it as responsive.js in my files.

I hope someone can tell me where I have gone wrong to make the slides move as it should.

Thanks.

Comment: how do I search for the code that you have formatted for me?

Comment: Nope. It's not working after I copied your formatted code to replace my code.  It is not working.  The image is still not moving at all.

Comment: you misunderstand. Your question was accompanied with very hard to read code. In the future please format it yourself using for example jsfiddle.net and then post a link to the fiddle here too

Comment: I see. So sorry I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Instead of using above script that contains the same elements.

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider4").responsive({
        auto: true,
        pager: false,
        nav: true,
        speed: 800,
        namespace: "callbacks"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You have initialised script two times,first one has typo error in this line`$("#slider4".rslides).responsive({`

Just add below script inside script tag

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider4").responsive({
        auto: true,
        pager: false,
        nav: true,
        speed: 800,
        namespace: "callbacks"
    });
})
```

Comment: Nope.  It's not working.  The image is still dead...not moving at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put jQuery code inside:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    // code
});
```

Maybe It's just not loading on the document load. I'm guessing though.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `responsiveSlides` instead of `responsive` because responsive is undefined function.